# Get an attribute from the clicked element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

**Goal**: get the `data-element` from the button that is been clicked.

My current code:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('my_buttons_class')).forEach((button) => {
     button.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
           e.preventDefault();
           /*
                Here i want to get the 'data-element' from the clicked button
                something like 
                e.target.attr('data-element');
           */
     })
});
```

The button element is something like this:

```html
<button class="my_buttons_class" data-element="some json">My button text</button>
```

**Current problem**: the listener works fine, but the `e.target` is just the HTML text of that element, so i can't use `.attr()` on it

Also already tried `e.target['data-element']` but it return undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`.attr()`**](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) is a jQuery method, In vanilla JavaScript you have to use [**`getAttribute()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to access the attribute:

```
e.target.getAttribute('data-element');
```

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('my_buttons_class')).forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-element'));        
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="my_buttons_class" data-element="some json">My button text</button>
```

Comment: Wonderful, was looking exactly for this, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `button` variable refers to the button being iterated over, so to access the `data-element` attribute of that element, use:

```
button.dataset.element
```

or, with `getAttribute`:

```
button.getAttribute('data-element')
```

Elements do not automatically get their attributes assigned as properties of their Javascript references - that only works for a certain few attribute types, like `id`, `class`, and `name`, which is why `e.target['data-element']` didn't work.

Comment: element should be "data-element"? but in js i can't use "-" in elements name

Comment: An attribute of `data-SOMETHINGHERE` can be accessed via `<element>.dataset.SOMETHINGHERE`. There's no need to use bracket notation - accessing the `dataset` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('my_buttons_class')).forEach((button) => {
     button.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
           e.preventDefault();
           console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-element'));
     })
});
```

```html
<button class="my_buttons_class" data-element="some json">My button text</button>
```